# i am getting list item same name where i keep the for loop in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

//i want to display list items in list view i am put all the items in list i want to display all the items in listview it is displaying but getting same names where i keep the for loop in getview.Please help me how can i pshow the list items in listview.

```
public class Listjava extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int i = 0;
    List<Contact> contacts;
    MyBaseAdapter adapter;
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contacts);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public MyBaseAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Contact> contacts) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return contacts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, null);
            }

            for (Contact cn : contacts) {
                String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName()
                        + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                // Writing Contacts to logsout

                System.out.println("log" + log);
                TextView title2 = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlsm_row); // title
                // String song = title.get(position).toString();
                title2.setText(cn.getName());

                TextView title22 = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row2); // notice

                title22.setText(cn.getPhoneNumber());
            }

            return vi;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use a loop. Get the `Contact cn` from the `contacts` List using the `position` parameter.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do it

Comment: You are returning null in getItem() method and don't use loop inside getView() method.see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the MyBaseAdapter class like below.

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            List<Contact> contacts;

            public MyBaseAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Contact> contacts) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.contacts = contacts;// Initialize here
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return contacts.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return contacts.get(position);// Changed
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position; //Changed
            }

            @Override
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View vi = convertView;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, null);
                    }
                    Contact cn = (Contact) getItem(position);
                        TextView title2 = (TextView) vi
                                .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlsm_row); // title
                        title2.setText(cn.getName());

                        TextView title22 = (TextView) vi
                                .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row2); // notice
                        title22.setText(cn.getPhoneNumber());
                    return vi;
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not add for loop inside the getView method instead use contacts list like this :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, null);
        }


            String log = "Id: " + contacts.get(position).getID() + " ,Name: " + contacts.get(position).getName()
                    + " ,Phone: " + contacts.get(position).getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to logsout

            System.out.println("log" + log);
            TextView title2 = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlsm_row); // title
            // String song = title.get(position).toString();
            title2.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());

            TextView title22 = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row2); // notice

            title22.setText(contacts.get(position).getPhoneNumber());


        return vi;
    }
```